# Scanf is reading ctrl+c on named-pipes program

Tags: c, scanf, named-pipes, kali-linux

I'm trying to make a named pipe or FIFO with a 2 C program (read & write). Both of this program is running on a while(1) loop.
These programs should be terminated when ctrl+c is pressed, but when I press ctrl+c on the **write** program, it still sending something to the **read** program. Its work fine if I input normal numbers, but when i press ctrl+c on the **write** program to terminate, it gives this random number to the **read** program

```
#normal numbers shows:
BMI: 16.1, Overweight

#on ctrl+c input:
BMI = 165534.6 (some random numbers)
```

This is the code for the **write** program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int fd, fd1, fd2;
    
    //FIFO file path
    char * myfifo = "/tmp/myfifo";

    mkfifo(myfifo,0666);

    float weight, height, bmi = 0;
    char arr1[80];
    while(1)
    {
        //open
        fd = open(myfifo, O_WRONLY);
        fd1 = open(myfifo, O_WRONLY);
        fd2 = open(myfifo, O_WRONLY);

        printf("Name            : ");
        scanf("%[^\n]", arr1);
        getchar();
        write(fd, arr1, strlen(arr1)+1);
        close(fd);
        
        printf("Body Weight in kg    : ");
        scanf("%f",  &weight);
        getchar();
        write(fd1, &weight, sizeof(weight));
        printf("%f\n", weight);
        close(fd1);

        printf("Body Height in cm    : ");
        scanf("%f",  &height);
        getchar();
        printf("\n---------------------------\n\n");
        write(fd2, &height, sizeof(height));
        printf("%f\n", height);
        close(fd2);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is the code for **read** program, it goes on a while(1) loop

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int fd, fd1, fd2;
    char * myfifo = "/tmp/myfifo";
    mkfifo(myfifo,0666);
    float weight, height, bmi = 0;
    char str1[80];
    while(1)
    {
        //First open in read only and read
        fd = open(myfifo, O_RDONLY);
        fd1 = open(myfifo, O_RDONLY);
        fd2 = open(myfifo, O_RDONLY);
        read(fd, str1, 80);
        read(fd1, &weight, sizeof(weight));
        read(fd2, &height, sizeof(height));
        
        height = (height / 100);
        
        bmi = weight / (height * height);

        //Print the read string and close
        printf("%s BMI : %.1f\n", str1, bmi);
        close(fd);
        close(fd1);
        close(fd2);

        if(bmi < 18.5)
        {
            printf("Details = Underweight\n");
        }
        else if(bmi >= 18.5 && bmi <= 22.9)
        {
            printf("Details = Normal\n");
        }
        else if(bmi >= 23.0 && bmi <= 24.9)
        {
            printf("Details = Overweight\n");
        }
        else if(bmi >= 25.0 && bmi <= 29.9)
        {
            printf("Details = Obese I (Obesitas Class I)\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Details = Obese II (Obesitas Class II)\n");
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

So, I wonder, is there a way to make ctrl+c terminate both of those processes? So that the **write** program won't send anything after cttrl+c is pressed. I think this problem occurs because the **read** program keeps reading some input from **write** even when ctrl+c is pressed.

Comment: What flavor/version of Linux?  ([this](https://askubuntu.com/q/150616/752947) may be helpful.)

Comment: @ryyker I'm using Kali Linux

Comment: Kali-Linux is unique, so that is a very relevant piece of information.  I edited your tags to reflect this.  BTW, You did not indicate whether anything in the previous link helped, ...  [here is another](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18589/ctrlc-does-not-work-in-gnome-terminal).  Feedback please?

Comment: @ryyker oh sorry for the late response, i don't think the ctrl+c doesn't works, but it just it doesn't stops the read program from reading input, since read program just waiting for input from **write**

Comment: Have you considered trapping the kill event (ctrl-c), then sending a string such as "Kill" to the reader before allowing the writer to terminate, The reader would need to _search_ each message.

Comment: @ryyker The problem is the check of the read() system calls. Look at my answer...

Comment: Read returns 0 upon EOF in the pipe meaning that it it closed on the other side. Otherwise it blocks waiting for data from the other side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you don't check that read() may return 0 in the reader. So, when it returns 0 (= 0 chars read), you display any garbage from your buffer. When read() returns 0, you should terminate the reader because it means that the other side is closed (the writer exited).

As a general rule, try to check all the return codes from the services/syscalls. You may make a first draft without checking anything. But when it appears to dysfunction, add the checks on the return codes. This usually helps...